# How to continue script if external executable returns error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an executable that I call from a python3 script that runs like:

```
def run_function(input_file):
    import os
    # format the input_file
    os.system("executable < input_file")

input_files = [ list_of_input_files ] 

for input_file in input_files:
    run_function(input_file)
```

The problem I have is that sometimes a given execution returns a failure, breaking the loop and crashing the script. I would like to know if there is a way to continue with the script if the external executable returns an error.

Comment: Have you tried putting the call to `os.system()` inside a `try`/`except` pair?

Comment: What error is being "returned"?

Comment: Usually, os.system does not crash the Python process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use try-except inside the for loop. Refer to the below mentioned url for more details. [Try-Except Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)